# Ag grid cell editing option as a dropdown with a text field too for typing value if not present in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

Ag grid allows to edit values in it's cell as text field or for selecting values from dropdown.
i have gone through this link https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/react/provided-cell-editors/#agrichselectcelleditor but it does not give an option to type if i want to enter a value that is not present in the dropdown. could anyone please help on this

i want to enter a value that is not present in the dropdown. i am expecting if a user wants to select from the dropdown values it's good if not they can type in it too.

Comment: The grid does not offer this - you are going to have to write a custom cell editor.