No input textbox shown for typing when agRichSelectCellEditor is used
I was trying to follow the tutorial (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/provided-cell-editors-rich-select/) to include a column with agRichSelectCellEditor so users can select the cell which has a drop down list that allows typing while search.  I am able to get the drop down but there is no textbox for typing.  My code looks exactly the same as the example.
<style media="only screen">
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

    html {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    body {
        padding: 1rem;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
<script>
    const colors = [
        'AliceBlue',
        'Azure',
        'Beige',
        'BurlyWood',
        'CadetBlue',
        'Cyan',
        'DarkBlue',
        'Wheat',
        'WhiteSmoke',
        'Yellow',
        'YellowGreen'
    ];

    function _nullishCoalesce(lhs, rhsFn) { if (lhs != null) { return lhs; } else { return rhsFn(); } }
    class ColourCellRenderer {


        init(params) {
            const eGui = this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
            eGui.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            eGui.style.textOverflow = 'ellipsis';

            const { value } = params;
            const colorSpan = document.createElement('span');
            const text = document.createTextNode(_nullishCoalesce(value, () => ('')));

            if (value != null) {
                colorSpan.style.borderLeft = '10px solid ' + params.value;
                colorSpan.style.paddingRight = '5px';
            }

            eGui.appendChild(colorSpan)
            eGui.append(text);
        }

        getGui() {
            return this.eGui;
        }

        refresh() {
            return false
        }
    }

    const columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: "Allow Typing (Match)",
            field: "color",
            cellRenderer: ColourCellRenderer,
            cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor",
            cellEditorParams: {
                values: colors,
                searchType: "match",
                allowTyping: true,
                filterList: true,
                highlightMatch: true,
                valueListMaxHeight: 220,
            },
        },
        {
            headerName: "Allow Typing (MatchAny)",
            field: "color",
            cellRenderer: ColourCellRenderer,
            cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor",
            cellEditorParams: {
                values: colors,
                searchType: "matchAny",
                allowTyping: true,
                filterList: true,
                highlightMatch: true,
                valueListMaxHeight: 220,
            },
        },
    ];

    function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
        // min and max included
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    const data = Array.from(Array(20).keys()).map(() => {
        const color = colors[getRandomNumber(0, colors.length - 1)];
        return { color };
    });

    let gridApi;

    const gridOptions = {
        defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
            editable: true,
        },
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: data,
    };

    // setup the grid after the page has finished loading
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const gridDiv = document.querySelector("#myGrid");
        gridApi = agGrid.createGrid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
    });
</script>

<div class="grid-container" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    <div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-alpine" style="height: 100%"></div>
</div>

I wonder if there is any specific version of ag grid script I need to include.  Please help! Thanks!
Gab

Can you make a reproducable example here? https://jsfiddle.net/

Please see revised version above..Thank you!

My issue is similar to this one here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74638037/ag-grid-cell-editing-option-as-a-dropdown-with-a-text-field-too-for-typing-value/78415002#78415002

Seems like you are trying to use an enterprise feature. Please check if:

You have added the imports for Ag-Grid enterprise.
You have a valid license key added to your application.


The license key must have added to my application since the previous developer had already used enterprise features.  How exactly should I import Ag-Grid enterprise on my new page though?  I have tried both  and also .  None seemed to work.

Anyone?? Please?

Following this didn't work? https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/licensing#setting-the-license-key
